What is "Explicit Propagation" Image Inpainting - LatentPaint Paper - Generative AI
I am trying to implement "Explicit Propagation" method for Image Inpainting introduced in LatentPaint Research paper.
This paper proposes the introduction of a module between VAE and Diffusion Model. The generated image at step t-1 (backward process) is merged with the forward process image at (t-1) by a masked combination of both of these images giving h* (Provided in this post below). Provided in the formula below.

Here is the provided algorithm where the authors introduces "Explicit Propagation" highlighted in yellow. Plz help me understand how this operation works.

The Explicit Propagation is explained here. I don't understand how this operation works.

Plz help me understand:

γ(D(m),hcond) - How this max pooling operation works as we are providing input and a mask. Given an input of W′×H′×C′ what would be the output of this part.
ϕ[ω;γ(D(m),hcond)] - How does the ϕ function work. what would be the output image dimensions after this function.
γ^(−1)[ϕ[ω;γ(D(m),hcond)]] - here we are unpooling - i am assuming it upsampling and interpolation and the output image h-hat will have the same size as hcond.
What do we do with this h-hat? In the Figure 3 it is shown that h-hat is combine with h* to make h-hat again. But how are they combined, i was not able to find any explanation on it.


Please, ask only one specific question per post (you can always create multiple posts!), even if the questions are all about one paper, and use mathjax to format your math symbols and equations.
